# Make Camel split options configurable using Java DSL

Tags: java, spring, properties, split, apache-camel

I have a splitter within my Camel route that looks like this...

```
from("direct:myRoute")
// Split each exchange into multiple sub-exchanges on the basis of MySplitter.class 
// Configure the splitter to stop on exception that comes up during processing of each sub-exchange
// Configure the splitter to share unit of work with the main exchange that means processing of the entire Exchange is an atomic success/failure
.split().method(MySplitter.class).stopOnException().shareUnitOfWork()
    //do something with each sub-exchange
    .to("direct:processEachSubExchange")
.end();
```

What I'd like to do is I'd want to keep the `stopOnException` as configurable. Which means that I would like to enable/disable the feature of stopping when an exception comes up on demand with the help of an externalized property.

Is this possible using Java DSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also direct the route using a choice block, then you could have content specific handling of exceptions.

```
from("{{somewhere.in.endpoint}}")
   .choice()
      .when(header("endOnExceptionFlag").isEqualTo(true))
         .to("direct:splitEndOnException")
      .otherwise()
         .to("direct:splitIgnoreExceptions")
   .endChoice()
.end()

// process split with exception handling
.from("direct:splitEndOnException")
   .split().method(MySplitter.class).stopOnException().shareUnitOfWork()
      .to("direct:processEachSubExchange")
.end();

// process split ignoring exceptions
.from("direct:splitIgnoreExceptions")
   .split().method(MySplitter.class).shareUnitOfWork()
      .to("direct:processEachSubExchange")
.end();
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use two different sub routes: one that stops on exceptions and another that doesn't. The sub route is chosen dynamically using a system property:

```
from("direct:start")
    .to("{{mySubRoute}}");;

from("direct:mySubRouteWithStopOnException")
    .split().method(MySplitter.class).stopOnException().shareUnitOfWork()
    .to("direct:processEachSubExchange")
    .end();

from("direct:mySubRouteWithoutStopOnException")
    .split().method(MySplitter.class).shareUnitOfWork()
    .to("direct:processEachSubExchange")
    .end();
```

E.g., set the system property as follows:

```
System.setProperty("mySubRoute", "direct:mySubRouteWithStopOnException");
```

In this example, the sub routes with stop on exception is chosen.